# Mobile game tutorial, saved on local data or server?

Tags: mobile, game-development

I can't quite figure out what is the best approach to tutorials on mobile games. Should the tutorial progress and its features (or some of it) be stored locally on the device or should it all come from the server?

(if someone has a guest account and a facebook account he may face the tutorial twice should it all be stored on the server, mind you)

Thanks in advance

I have a mixture of the two but it gets in the way when I revisit it

Comment: This is gaming question not a developing one. answer is in online games your all data saved in a server not on your local device.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. As much as I like playing games, I also develop them for a living. I was wondering if anyone had some insight on a development approach rather than a specific line of code.

Is your answer based on the word 'online' or do you have any experience dealing with the topic?

Comment: Hi STTX and welcome to SO! This question is borderline off topic for Stack Overflow. Check the On-Topic page! https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic Please consider other StackExchange forums that might be better suited. Maybe this is suitable for https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: cheers, thanks for the links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial progression status is the part of the user progress. If you have any information about the user progress store tutorial status there.
The bigger problem though is user identification. Is this user someone who have played the game before or a newcomer? Is this registered user who we think it is or is it a different person? There is no other (feasible) way to confidently answer these questions, you can either make a guess based off the user behavior, or simply ask the user if he have played through the tutorial before. Or more correct if he wants to play it.